# Debugging PIMPL in Visual Studio(2012)

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I've got a DLL with following class:

Cat.h:

```
#ifndef CAT_H
#define CAT_H

class __declspec( dllexport ) Cat
{
    class CatImpl;  // Not defined here
    CatImpl *cat_;  // Handle
public:
    Cat();
    int a;
}; 

#endif
```

Cat.cpp:

```
#include "Cat.h"

class Cat::CatImpl
{
public:
    int c1;
    int c2;
};

Cat::Cat()
{
    cat_ = new Cat::CatImpl();
    cat_->c1 = 1; 
}
```

Then I've got a project(in separate solution) creating an instance of this class:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "..\..\DLL\DLL\Cat.h"

int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  int nCmdShow
)
{
    Cat cat;
    int x = 0;
}
```

Now I'm placing a breakpoint at the line:

```
int x = 0;
```

and open Quickwatch window:
[image]

Symbols are loaded and *(cat.cat_) doesn't work:

[image]

Is there any way to view the contents of cat_?

The only way I have come up with so far is:

```
(int)(*((char*)cat.cat_ + 0))
```

Also why is the following returning 0?:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `*(cat.cat_)`?

Comment: Have you loaded symbols for the library? I mean the part _not defined here_.

Comment: At the point you show there aren't any contents. You have to create a new instance of `Cat::CatImpl` first. Try 'step into' ...

Comment: I've edited the post, nothing works.

Comment: @stiopa It really looks that debug symbols for the interns of your DLL aren't available when you're debugging.

Comment: Is the .pdb for the DLL in the same directory as your DLL.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ: what do you mean by " interns of your DLL aren't available when you're debugging"? The DLL with Cat class is DLL.dll and it says that the symbols are loaded? Unless I'm missing something?

cup: yes pdb is in the same dir as DLL.dll

Comment: @stiopa If the symbols are loaded, you should be able to set a breakpoint on `new CatImpl()` and step into the constructor from there (if you have a non default one). If you're not able to do that and have a non default constructor, then you're missing debug symbols.

Comment: @W.B: I can step into the constructor and see the value of c1 from there, but the question is how do I see that value without having to step into the constructor? 
The only way I have come up with is looking at the pointer address in the Memory window, which is easy in this simple example, but not that simple in a real situation I need to use it in...

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is to add a watch on the value, where you ["cast"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/context-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019) it to the DLL that contains the impl. So in your case that would be.

```
(DLL.dll!Cat::CatImpl*)cat.cat_
```

Comment: this worked for me